# Texstudio is not working

Tags: software-installation, libreoffice, texlive, wps-office

I'm using ubuntu 16.04. Since a few days, my apps are not responding properly. It first happened to WPS office (I installed it yesterday, and it was not working from the beginning). When I try to launch from the search menu or try to open a file, then the icon appears but nothing else. But my Texstudio was working fine yesterday, but now it is also showing similar behavior. Also, the libre office is behaving the same way.

If anyone knows how to fix it, then please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you run the command `texstudio` in a terminal?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi. The same thing happens even if I try to open it from a terminal. i.e. Only the icon but no window.